# Rename a section in a Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2010. It looks like this:

[image]

I would like it too look like this:

[image]

How do I change the name of the section from `ReportFooterSection1` to `Section4`?

- Unfortunately the Section Expert has no option for renaming a section.
- The `.cs` code that is associated with the `*.rpt` file does expose the section name and I can change it; unfortunately, when I reopen the `.rpt` file my changes are lost.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the `.rpt` file.
2. Open the Properties Window. (View > Properties Window).
3. Click the section to rename.
4. Rename it.

[image]